# jquery show more ellements ..similar with infinite scroll issue

Tags: jquery, scroll, show-hide

I have more "row" div's and what I try to do is that when the user click on a button 5 more "row's" are show... and when he click again it show another 5 more 
also the reverse operation for this!
Do you have any idea how I can obtain this effect ?

what I did since now:

```
$('.row:gt(1)').hide(); //show just two row's

$('.showmore').live('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.row').not(':visible').each( function() {

        $(this).nextAll(':lt(3)').slideDown();

    });
});
```

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/SFkzs/

Thanks for your time!

Comment: are you trying to show 5 more and hide the previous 5? or is 'the reverse' just hiding 5 rows at a time?

Comment: like in the preview..first show just 2 ..and after when user click 'show more' show the next div's (maximum 5)
the preview div remain visible

Comment: I'd understood that out the gate. I was wondering what the implication of 'also the reverse operation for this' was? Which was what I was attempting to clarify above, but I'm pretty sure I've got a clear understanding.

Comment: You really shouldn't use `live` anymore.  Have a look at `on`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will show the next 5 hidden rows:

```
$('.row:hidden:lt(5)').slideDown();
```

One (of many) way to hide the last 5 visible is this:

```
$($('.row:visible').get().reverse()).filter(":lt(5)").slideUp();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SFkzs/2

Comment: @menocchio Updated.  Though an approach with `slice` may be a bit "cleaner".

Comment: hmm..like..? I'm new on jquery ...
..but based on your first input I manage to do the slide up :)
http://jsfiddle.net/SFkzs/3/

Comment: the reverse at the end show just 1 div not 2 ..will be nice that on reverse at the end to have again the two div show 

anyway ..thank you .. I was spend some couple of hrs on this and with no result :-s